# Android - Starting Thread from Synchronized Block

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

Any ideas, why this part of code is locking the UI Thread?

```
synchronized (executionMonitor) {
    thread = new Thread(asyncCommand);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    thread.setName(command.getClass().getSimpleName());
    thread.start();
    return;
}
```

I'm starting the thread from the UI block. During debuging I found, that UI thread is in MONITOR state. But I don't understand why?

executionMonitor is defined only as object:

```
private Object executionMonitor = new Object();
```

and not used in other places.

Comment: *I'm starting the thread from the UI block* + *and not used in other places.* ... then why you need synchronization at all?

Comment: You should synchronize when you wish to achieve mutual exclusion, why would you need to synchronize a block in order to fire a thread,when you have only the ui thread firing it anyway? drop you synchronization block, further, if your are experiencing issues running tasks inside your main UI then try `runOnUiThread (Runnable action)` and fire anything from there,also i cannot understand why you return from the synchronized block. Threading&Synchronization is a complex issue, and if you are not experienced enough with it, it will hurt. try using built in objects  such as `Executor` services.

Comment: @Selvin - this is not my code, I'm trying to understand why the UI is locked

Comment: Don't assume that the author of the code knew what he/she was doing.  There's a lot of bad code out there running the world's systems.  A `synchronized` block should be small:  It should perform no more than a few reads and writes that need to be done as an atomic unit.  A well designed program would not do anything as complicated as creating a new instance or starting a thread inside a synchronized block.  Your example references three free variables:  `asyncCommand`, `thread`, and `command`.  I would dig in and find out why/whether any of those really requires synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I found, thank you all for replies, the problem was another stupid synchronization block - but in the command. Whole command was synchronized using the instance of DBHelper.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning outside the synchronized block.

Update:

Confirmed as not the solution - Java will automatically release the lock even if the return statement is inside the synchronized block

Comment: If I remove the block, then it's working, but my question is not - how to repair that. I would like to understand, why synchronized block indicates, that the UI is blocked until the execution thread comes back to this class.

Comment: That really is interesting. Is that the only line where you synchronize on executionMonitor?

Comment: Are you saying, just move the `return` statement out of the synchronized block?  How would that help?

Comment: you are right, it doesn't. in the meantime I've read a few things about it. Java automatically releases the lock even if the return is inside the synchronized block. my idea was it could be like a goto in C/C++ inside a function which would not pop the stack.